# What are these egg looking things on my rosemary?

Tags: diagnosis, pests

I don't think this should be part of [my other question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31269/whats-causing-the-yellow-spots-on-my-rosemary), but if it should be, let me know.

This is the same rosemary plant that I mentioned in [my other question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31269/whats-causing-the-yellow-spots-on-my-rosemary), and as I noted, it was improving. After all the ladybugs left, I sprayed it down with neem as stormy suggested. I was fooling around with my new magnifier when I noticed that there were egg-like spheres on the bottom of my rosemary leaves. Should I be concerned? Do I need to do anything more?
[image]

Next to ruler for scale:
[image]

Front of leaf:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are probably more than likely spider mite eggs.  So keep an eye open and spray again when they hatch.[spider mite eggs](http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrTcc7WguFYtjYAULInnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByb2lvbXVuBGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzcg--/RV=2/RE=1491202902/RO=10/RU=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.growerstrust.com%2Fblogs%2Fnews%2F7307612-how-to-kill-spider-mite-eggs/RK=0/RS=zrhovC2BXUTMjuJZBxiX4FLXRBk-)

Comment: So I just keep on spraying neem when I see the mites until they go away?

Comment: Until you have them in control.  Spider mite is so tenacious...I am having to finally use a FOGGER to kill

Comment: My problem is IN DOORS where there are no predators.  These guys are everywhere and if you keep you plants healthy and water the foliage often should keep them in check.  Another spray will be important aftere all these eggs hatch will be all that is necessary, I think...